# How can I select cell values by color and paste them to a separate column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

My column values represent multiple choice answers to a question. The cell which is considered "correct" is colored green. I want to automatically pick the "correct" answer and paste it in a separate column. How can I achieve this, is there a VBA solution for this?

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: Like you want to copy the green answers from columns A to D into column E? With the green you have, you could check if a cell is green with `If cell.Font.Color = RGB(155, 187, 89)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, something like this should work:

```
Sub CopyGreen()
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Font.Color = RGB(155, 187, 89) Then cell.Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 5)
Next cell
End Sub
```

This assumes there is only one correct answer per row.